# How can I set Headers with Silverlight GET HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, httpwebrequest

Making a request to a RESTful service in Silverlight with HttpWebRequest works well so long as I don't add any headers to the request.

As soon as I add a header using code like this

```
var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(_RemoteAddress, "GetProviderMetadata"));
webReq.Method = HttpMethodType.Get;
webReq.Headers["SomeToken"] = "someTokenValue";
```

I get the exception pasted at the bottom of this question as soon as `EndGetResponse()` is called.  Anyone know why this is?  Adding headers to get requests seems to work fine in normal .NET so I'm guessing it's some sort of Silverlight limitation but I can't find any documentation that clarifies.

```
   {System.NotSupportedException ---> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
  at System.Net.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__b(Object state2)
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)}
   [System.NotSupportedException]: {System.NotSupportedException ---> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
  at System.Net.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__b(Object state2)
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)}
   _className: "System.NotSupportedException"
   _data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
   _dynamicMethods: null
   _exceptionMethod: null
   _exceptionMethodString: null
   _helpURL: null
   _HResult: -2146233067
   _innerException: {System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
  at System.Net.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)}
   _message: ""
   _remoteStackIndex: 0
   _remoteStackTraceString: null
   _source: "System.Windows"
   _stackTrace: {sbyte[192]}
   _stackTraceString: null
   _xcode: -532462766
   _xptrs: 0
   Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
   HelpLink: null
   HResult: -2146233067
   InnerException: {System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
  at System.Net.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)}
   Message: ""
   Source: "System.Windows"
   StackTrace: "   at System.Net.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)\r\n   at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Intellidimension.RdfEntity.Service.RemoteEntityServiceProviderClient.getProviderMetadataResponse(IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__b(Object state2)\r\n   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)\r\n   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)"
   System.Runtime.InteropServices._Exception.HelpLink: null
   System.Runtime.InteropServices._Exception.Source: "System.Windows"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight only supports setting headers using the POST method not the GET method. This is due to a limitation in how the TCP/IP stack is implemented in Silverlight. It uses the browser extension APIs instead of going directly against the host OS's APIs.

Comment: I was guessing this might be the case.  Do you have a link to MSDN docs that explain this limitation?  I was not able to find anything.

Comment: The closest thing I was able to find is the list at the bottom of this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection(VS.95).aspx Certain headers are restricted based on the Method and the URI.

Answer (score 5):

Specify ["Client HTTP" handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) before you call you initiate your WebRequest.

Like this:

```
bool httpResult = WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
bool httpsResult = WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```

Comment: I have verified that using ClientHttp allows setting headers on GET requests, although I'm creating each WebRequest as ClientHttp like this: `var request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.Browser.WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(endpoint);` BrowserHttp restricts headers on GET requests (as the previous answer describes) but ClientHttp does not.